# Redirection using file descriptors - specific example

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection, file-descriptors

I am reading [this documentation](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/sect_05_02.html) which gives the following examples about redirection and file descriptors.

> ```
> ls > dirlist 2>&1
> ```
>
> will direct both standard output and standard error to the file
>   dirlist, while the command
>
> ```
> ls 2>&1 > dirlist
> ```
>
> will only direct standard output to dirlist. This can be a useful
>   option for programmers.

Are these examples the wrong way round? It seems to me the *second* example "will direct both standard output and standard error to the file dirlist" while the *first* example "will only direct standard output to dirlist".

If I'm wrong about this (...probably...) can someone explain the logic of these 2 examples clearly?

Comment: Side note: The Bash guide you've linked to is heavily **not** recommended.  Instead, check out the [Wooledge Bash Guide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to understand the `n>&m` syntax. this is a duplication operation, meaning copy m to n. check out section ["3.6.8 Duplicating File Descriptors"](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html).

I had the same doubt as you when I studied the article. So I can try to explain it to you:

```
ls > dirlist 2>&1
```

with the above command, you first redirect the output to dirlist by `> dirlist`.  `2>&1` means copy file descriptor 1 to 2, in other words make fd2 a copy of fd1.  Now fd1 is already pointed to dirlist, making fd2 a copy of fd1 means fd2 also points to dirlist. As a result, fd1->dirlist, fd2->dirlist.

```
ls 2>&1 > dirlist
```

with this, you first make fd2 a copy of fd1 which is still the terminal, so fd2->terminal. then you redirect fd1 to dirlist. as a result, fd2 -> terminal, fd1->dirlist.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think the part that is confusing me is "2>&1 means copy file descriptor 1 to 2, in other words make fd2 a copy of fd1". I had the impression that 2>&1 meant exactly the opposite: i.e. copy file descriptor 2 to 1 so that the contents of 1 include the contents of 2. Reading left to right i can't see the logic of how 2>&1 ("take fd2 and send it to fd1", as i am reading it) actually means "make fd2 a copy of fd1". What am i missing?

Comment: @penname its just how the syntax is, you just need to remember it. Check out section "3.6.8 duplicating file descriptor" of this page this page: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html

Answer (score 1):

The directions are processed left to right.

```
ls > dirlist 2>&1
```

makes the shell which will eventually turn itself into ls, do the following system calls (error checking omitted for brevity).

```
/* Handle > dirlist */
int temp_fd = open("dirlist",O_WR);  /* Open dirlist for output */
dup2(temp_fd, 1); /* Make file descriptor 1 (stdout) point to dirlist */
close(temp_fd);  /* Don't need this other file descriptor for dirlist */
/* Handle 2>&1 */
dup2(1,2); /* Make fd 2 be a copy of fd 1, which points to dirlist */
```

So first fd 1 is changed, and then fd 2 is changed.

Conversely ls 2>&1 > dirlist does

```
/* Handle 2>&1 */
dup2(1,2); /* Make fd 2 be a copy of fd 1, the original stdout */
/* Handle > dirlist */
int temp_fd = open("dirlist",O_WR);  /* Open dirlist for output */
dup2(temp_fd, 1); /* Make file descriptor 1 (stdout) point to dirlist */
close(temp_fd);  /* Don't need this other file descriptor for dirlist */
```

A different way to look at it is as just assignments. Originally fd1=initial_stdout, then

```
/* ls > dirlist 2>&1 */
fd1=to_dirlist
fd2=fd1 (i.e. to_dirlist)

/* ls 2>&1 > dirlist */
fd2=fd1 (i.e. initial_stdout)
fd1=to_dirlist.
```

Or you can say `copy by value` rather than `copy by reference`.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. I need to go through it more slowly, and then i may have some questions. In the meantime, can i ask: what tool did you use to view the system calls? Knowing this depth of detail is a big help.

Comment: @penname, I didn't look at system calls, this is just knowledge I have acquired over the years (which means it may be wrong!). If you want to look yourself, then the most common tool to use would be `strace -f -o /tmp/strace/out ....`. A newer tool would be  http://www.sysdig.org/, or even the bpf stuff in the linux kernel. To show my age, truss for solaris would be the correct tool.