# Use of '&' with file descriptors

Tags: linux, io-redirection

When using redirection of this form 2 > &1, why is there an '&' before 1 but not before 2?

Comment: You shouldn't think of the `&` as part of a filename-like thing (i.e. `&1` meaning file descriptor 1); it's part of the `>&` redirection operator. In fact, `2 > &1` will get you an error message because there cannot be a space between `>` and `&`, and putting a space between `2` and `>&` means the `2` is not part of the redirection operator, it's just an unrelated command argument, but you *can* put a space between `>&` and `1`, so `2>& 1` will work fine.

Comment: It doesn't really answer *this* question, but see our canonical reference,  [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/80216)

Comment: Why would there be? Or, are you wondering why the redirection syntax doesn't have that `&` on the left side always, even with a filename, e.g. `&2>errors.out`? Wouldn't that be just an extra nuisance to write over `2>errors.out`

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a question of _why_ some syntax is the way it is basically a matter of opinion. Of course if, when this feature was originally introduced, the developers had picked whatever other syntax you'd prefer, we might well be seeing questions as to why it's not this instead.

Answer (score 1):

The `>&` denotes a file descriptor duplication operation.  `1` and `2` are the actual file descriptor references.
The subject of file descriptor duplication is explained in more detail here (and within that article's references):
[Redirection using file descriptors - specific example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/325040/redirection-using-file-descriptors-specific-example)